# Distribution estimation

Tags: density-estimation

What would be a good strategy for estimating the joint distribution of a bunch of measurements?

So if I had drawn from a 2D Gaussian I would have given vectors:

```
[[ 3.30598028  4.42541811]  
 [ 2.53505053  1.29456389]  
 [ 0.66794753 -0.36475196]  
 ...,                       
 [ 2.54780722 -0.19608394]  
 [ 2.99712014  4.57796175]  
 [ 3.07760632  3.35089218]]
```

and I would somehow like to figure out that this somewhat looks like a 2D Gaussian.
Except in my case the vectors are actually 16 bytes and I don't know what the bits are. I am hoping to gain some insight into the format by looking at the joint distribution.

When I say I have a vectors of 16 bytes I mean I have 128 values which can be either 0 or 1. The distribution is not from a specific family.

Essentially I am looking for things like

- "the second bit is always the same as the fourths" or
- "every eights bit is always zero (maybe this is ascii encoded)" or
- "the third bit is always the xor of the first two bits"

How do I best approach this?

Comment: I think we are going to need more detail here. Do you have a family of distributions to select from? Do you mean the vectors of of length 16 and the contents lie in [0,,255] or something else?

Comment: @mdewey I edit the question a bit, Does that help?

Comment: It's still confusing--there seems to be little connection between your discussion of 2D Gaussian distributions and your description of "vectors" and "bytes."  Are you trying to say that each observation is a vector of 128 binary (0/1) values and that you're trying to estimate the joint distribution of all 128 components?

Comment: @whuber Yes, I want the joint distribution of all 128 components. And sorry about the confusion I just wanted to add an example of what I am roughly trying to do.

Comment: You really need to give us much more context! To estimate a 128-dim joint distribution is a very ambitious goal, do you really need it? What is your ultimate goal, which question do you ask from the data?